# Is there projection/filter support for golang grpc protobuf stack?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

we are using golang grpc protobuf as our server stack, I am wondering is there projection feature where I can filter certain fields in the response?

Answer (score 0):

A [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#field-masks-in-projections) may be used in this way. According to the docs:

> When a FieldMask specifies a projection, the API will filter the response message (or sub-message) to contain only those fields specified in the mask.